# Using built-in function(PCA) in pyscripter

Tags: python, pca, pyscripter

Can anyone suggest how to use PCA built in function in pyscripter. As a start i imported pca

```
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA
```

and then code area,

```
results = PCA(arr1)
print("-----------------------PCA-----------------------")
print(results)
```

where arr1 is the dataset(numerical) read from a file.But I am getting Attrubute error as:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\pooja\Documents\project\traingsom.py", line 282, in <module>
 results = PCA(arr1)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 845, in __init__
 n, m = a.shape
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0):

In the source code of mlab, it says '`*a*: a numobservations x numdims array`'.
You should use it like this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.mlab import PCA

dataMatrix = np.array(aListOfLists)   # Convert a list-of-lists into a numpy array.  aListOfLists is the data points in a regular list-of-lists type matrix.
myPCA = PCA(dataMatrix)   # make a new PCA object from a numpy array object
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thank you..I modified but now error is:                        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pooja\Documents\project\pca.py", line 37, in <module>
    myPCA = PCA(dataMatrix)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mlab.py", line 845, in __init__
    n, m = a.shape
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack............
And i would like to know whether this PCA inbuilt function does all those mean,covariance etc calculations too

Comment: @Devi It seems not. You have to make para passed through right first.